# DE-specific startup applications?

Tags: gnome, startup, desktop-environments

I want certain applications (such as indicator-multiload) to run at startup *only if* I sign into Unity, not GNOME-shell. I also want some other applications to only start in GNOME-shell (like Shutter).

Is there, say, something I can add before the command in "Startup Applications" that does this for me? Or do I need to install some sort of extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a starting point for your question. You can place a conditional statement withing the command to execute field in the Startup Application. This command will check what is the current desktop session and will act based on that. E.g.

> if [ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" == "ubuntu" ]; then (echo "Unity"); else (echo "Gnome") ; fi

The condition checks if it is Unity session and prints Unity if true. Otherwise, it will print Gnome.
You can replace the echo commands with any command you wish to execute or omit the else part.
Another example:

> if [ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" == "ubuntu" ]; then (shutter); fi

This will run Shutter application only in Unity.